# Flutter FirebaseAuth: How can i check if a User is LoggedIn in a void?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am new in FirebaseAuth and i want, that in a void it check if the User is LoggedIn and if not, that he will be redirected.

That is my void:

```
  void newEntry() {
    showDialog<AlertDialog>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return neuerEintrag(addItem);
        });
  }
```

And this is my check if the User os LoggedIn, in an other class:

```
    class loginProfile extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AuthService auth = Provider.of(context).auth;
    return StreamBuilder<String>(
      stream: auth.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          final bool signedIn = snapshot.hasData;
          return signedIn ? Profil() : FirstView();
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using the `currentUser` synchronous getter would be enough?

```
if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {...}
```

ref: https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/currentUser.html